# How to configure Renovate to update dependencies based on GitHub tags?

Tags: renovate

I would like Renovate to scan through a yml file and update this value using GitHub tags as the datasource, with these tags being in another GitHub repository. Both of the repositories are private and have Renovate installed on them.

#### Repo A - `renovate-test`

This repo contains the following in yml:

```yaml
ref: refs/tags/exampleTag/1.0.0
```

#### Repo B - `renovate-test-tags`

`exampleTag/1.0.0`

#### Renovate Config

I have added the following in my Renovate config:

```json
    "regexManagers": [
      {
        "fileMatch": [
          ".*y[a]?ml$"
        ],
        "matchStrings": [
          "refs\/tags\/(?<depName>.*)\/(?<currentValue>.*)"
        ],
        "datasourceTemplate": "github-tags"
      }
    ]
```

This leads to the following errors:

```json
DEBUG: Datasource unknown error
{
  "datasource": "github-tags",
  "packageName": "exampleTag",
  "err": {
    "message": "Variable $name of type String! was provided invalid value",
    "stack": "Error: Variable $name of type String! was provided invalid value
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "baseBranch": "main",
  "config": {
    "regex": [
      {
        "deps": [
          {
            "depName": "exampleTag",
            "currentValue": "1.0.0",
            "datasource": "github-tags",
            "replaceString": "refs/tags/exampleTag/1.0.0",
            "updates": [],
            "warnings": [
              {
                "topic": "exampleTag",
                "message": "Failed to look up github-tags dependency exampleTag"
              }
            ],
            "versioning": "semver"
          }
        ],
        "matchStrings": [
          "refs/tags/(?<depName>.*)/(?<currentValue>.*)"
        ],
        "datasourceTemplate": "github-tags",
        "packageFile": "pipeline.yml"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Additionally, would I need to specify `registryUrlTemplate` to point to the tags repo? 
Something like `https://github.com/<org_name>/renovate-test-tags`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you are seeing is coming from the Github API.

The `github-tags` datasource expects a `depName` in the style of `<organization>/<repository>` as seen in the url.

If `https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol` is the URL to the repository you want to have `StackExchange/dnscontrol` as `depName`.

You can hardcode the ORG like this:

```json
    "regexManagers": [
      {
        "fileMatch": [
          ".*y[a]?ml$"
        ],
        "matchStrings": [
          "refs\/tags\/(?<depName>.*)\/(?<currentValue>.*)"
        ],
        "datasourceTemplate": "github-tags",
        "depNameTemplate": "<org_name>/{{{depName}}}"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: That fixed the specific error I was seeing but I also had to add the following to actually get it to create the PR's.

`"extractVersionTemplate": "^{{{depName}}}\/(?<version>.*)$"`

Comment: If you have to do this your `matchStrings` are wrong. `extractVersionTemplate` is used for example to remove the leading `v` from `v1.0.0`.